# Have a array or list represent several properties in a auto generated partial class

Tags: c#

I have a class that is a auto generated partial class.

In this class it generates 5 properties like:

```
public double AW1 {get; set;}
public double AW2 {get; set;}
public double AW3 {get; set;}
public double AW4 {get; set;}
public double AW5 {get; set;}
```

Edit:  I should mention these properties do have some custom set logic which I would want to execute when they do change values.

In many situations it would be very handy to treat these properties as a array or list.

I thought I could do something like:

```
    public double[] AW
    {
        get
        {
            double[] AWList = new double[]
            {
                AW1,
                AW2,
                AW3,
                AW4,
                AW5,
            };
            return AWList;
        }

        private set
        {
            AW1 = value[0];
            AW2 = value[1];
            AW3 = value[2];
            AW4 = value[3];
            AW5 = value[4];
        }
    }
```

But there must be a better way to do it then this way.

Comment: I have run into situations like this before too, so frustrating! I have used reflection to handle these situations somewhat dynamically by implying the collection by type, but I haven't had any success either.

Comment: Auto generated? How? Can't you tweak the generation process, or, better, improve the structure of the underlying classes or tables (i.e. normalization)?